# Django Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys

OK, similar questions asked before don't seem to have a working answer to this.
I have a Django application which was working well but now using the models in a web-based app or on the command line give me the above error. All my tables are Innodb and I have run syncdb. switching off integrity checking seems counterintuitive.  My apologies if I'm missing the obvious either here or in the previous replies. Any help, gratefully received.

From models.py

```
class difficulty(models.Model):
    difficultyName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    difficultyDescription = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blank=False;
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.difficultyName


class task(models.Model):
    question     = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dateEntered  = models.DateTimeField('date entered') #, editable=False)
    difficulty   = models.ForeignKey(difficulty)
    taskClass    = models.ManyToManyField(taskClass,related_name ='taskClass')
    keyword      = models.ManyToManyField(keyword)
    service      = models.ManyToManyField(service)#, default = service.objects.get(serviceName='Medicine'))
    answer       = models.ManyToManyField(answer,  related_name = 'taskAnswer')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "A task - {0}\n with difficulty {1}\n and date {2}\n".format(self.question, self.difficulty, self.dateEntered)
```

In views.py the object is instantiated and saved as follows

```
if form.is_valid():                         # All validation rules pass
    theNewTask = form.save(commit=False)
    theNewTask.dateEntered = timezone.now()
    theNewTask.save()      # the rest of the method deals with many-to-many relationships in the task class
```

which gives the following error when processed through the template-based web form:

> Exception Value: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`djangoimp`.`twomt_task`, CONSTRAINT
>   `difficulty_id_refs_id_eca4bfb0` FOREIGN KEY (`difficulty_id`)
>   REFERENCES `TwoMT_difficulty` (`id`))')

using the classes at the python command line:

```
>> import twomt.models as T
>> from django.utils import timezone
>> task = T.task(question="where is spain")
>> task.dateEntered = timezone.now()
>> task.difficulty = T.difficulty.objects.get(id=2)
>> task.save()
```

Gives Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  ---- sniped out traceback ---
>   IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`djangoimp`.`twomt_task`, CONSTRAINT
>   `difficulty_id_refs_id_eca4bfb0` FOREIGN KEY (`difficulty_id`)
>   REFERENCES `TwoMT_difficulty` (`id`))')

but the instantiated class is fine:

```
>>> print task
A task - where is spain
 with difficulty Medium
 and date 2015-03-19 11:19:04.494322+00:00

>>> print  T.difficulty.objects.get(id=2)
Medium
```

SHOW COLUMNS FROM TwoMT_task gives

```
Field           Type           Null   Key     Default   Extra
'question',     'varchar(200)','NO',  '' ,    NULL,     ''
'id',           'int(11)',     'NO',  'PRI',  NULL,     'auto_increment'
'difficulty_id','int(11)',     'NO',  'MUL',  NULL,      ''
'dateEntered',  'datetime',    'NO',  ' ',    NULL,      ''
```

SHOW COLUMNS FROM twomt_difficulty gives

```
Field                  Type           Null   Key     Default   Extra
'id',                  'int(11)',     'NO',  'PRI',  NULL,     'auto_increment'
'difficultyName',      'varchar(40)', 'NO',   '',    NULL,     ''
'difficultyDescription','varchar(200)','NO',  '',    NULL,     ''
```

Comment: My guess is that you have something screwed up at the table level since you're not using migrations. Can you run ```SHOW COLUMNS FROM TwoMT_difficulty``` and ```SHOW COLUMNS FROM twomt_task``` and include that in the question?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply - SHOW COLUMN RESULTS ADDED ??

Comment: -  I use make migrations and migrate but there are none to apply - is this something else I'm missing :-(

Comment: OK so I fixed this and maybe this swill help others. I deleted the foreign key and re-created it with exactly the same parameters and  . . . I then had a problem with the next foreign key updated in my python so I did the same again . .  twice. Now the code works fine and my foreign keys are in place so no loss of integrity checking. I WOULD LOVE TO KNOW WHY

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and solved with this link:

https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-resolve-error-1452-23000-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails/

## resume (from link):

ERROR 1452 (23000) is generated because some current values in child column cid of the referencing table orders are not in the parent column id of the referenced table customers. It already has violated the rule of constraint before we actually create it. Therefore, MySQL was unable to create the constraint.

### Solution

So now, you have to identify the rows that violate the constraint and correct them. Is it a hard work? Not really. You may use the following statement to identity the rows:

```sql
mysql> select * from orders where cid not in (select distinct id from customers);
```